# MySQL JOIN ON AND vs WHERE order of operations/optimal performance: which is best?

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization

I have two simple tables:

```
notes: note_id, user_id, game_id
users: user_id, user_name
```

I want to get a list of all notes for a game, with the `user_name`s of their owner.

The way I see it, there are three ways to do this.

**Simple JOIN WHERE:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM notes 
LEFT JOIN users ON notes.user_id = users.user_id 
WHERE notes.game_id = 1;
```

*EXPLAINed:*

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+----------------------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                       | key          | key_len | ref                  | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+----------------------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | notes | ref    | note_game_id,note_comment_note_id,note_like_note_id | note_game_id | 4       | const                |    1 |       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                             | PRIMARY      | 4       | tmp_db.notes.user_id |    1 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+----------------------+------+-------+
```

Although the most straightforward in syntax, it seems that this might perform the join on the two potentially massive (10k+) tables, then throw out everything but the 100 or so notes meeting the `WHERE` criteria. (wasted work)

**SUB QUERY**

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM notes 
      WHERE game_id = 1) AS n 
LEFT JOIN users ON n.user_id = users.user_id;
```

*EXPLAINed:*

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                                       | key          | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                               |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | NULL  | NULL | NULL                                                | NULL         | NULL    | NULL | NULL | Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables |
|  2 | DERIVED     | notes | ref  | note_game_id,note_comment_note_id,note_like_note_id | note_game_id | 4       |      |    1 |                                                     |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Makes intuitive sense- reduce the list of 10k rows to 100 before performing join. However, the subquery might destroy the index (not sure about this- more info would be appreciated). Also, subqueries do weird thing to in-memory caches (again, talking out of my ass here. any clarification would be greatly helpful.).

**JOIN ON**

```
SELECT * 
FROM notes 
LEFT JOIN users ON notes.game_id = 1 AND notes.user_id = users.user_id;
```

*EXPLAINed:*

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                  | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | notes | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                 |    4 |       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | tmp_db.notes.user_id |    1 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+-------+
```

From other similar threads on SO, it looks like this is recommended. However, when I `EXPLAIN` this query, I am told that there are no usable keys on the notes table (does it then have to iterate through EVERY note, throwing out the ones it won't bother joining?)

***So, these are my questions:***
What is the optimal way to make this query? Is there another way to go about it not listed? Why is one better than the other? What indexes should I use to ensure optimal use?

This seems like a very common/basic use case of joins, yet I cannot find the answer. I have found similar questions, but don't believe this is a duplicate. But, if I am wrong, please direct me. Thanks!

*edit*: added `EXPLAIN`ations at request. They are indeed different, but unfortunately not detailed enough for me to make much use of. Note that some possible keys listed are not part of the tables described at the top of the post- that is because I left out irrelevant details that exist in my specific problem.

Comment: If your only concern is performance, use `EXPLAIN` to see if they result in different query plans. They might all be treated equivalently. I'm pretty sure the first and last will be.

Comment: See my edit: they are in fact quite different. I am not experienced enough to make 100% sense of the explanations, but I can see that they are different in not-intuitively-better ways...

Comment: I suspect the reason they're different is because it's a `LEFT JOIN`. Although it shouldn't matter in this case, since the `game_id` column is in the first table, not the one being `LEFT JOIN`ed. The MySQL optimizer is not very good.

Comment: Do you really need a `LEFT JOIN` for this? Can there be a note whose `user_id` isn't in the `users` table?

Comment: hmm. I guess I just assumed LEFT JOIN would be faster (doesn't need to check existence in both tables)- is that assumption false? And you are correct- with just `JOIN`, the top and bottom queries have identical `EXPLAIN`s. does that mean identical queries?

Comment: Either way, my initial question is unanswered... do you know the order of operations applied in these queries (ie, is filter first, then join? or the other way around?)? Which method is the preferred?

Comment: It may actually depend on the contents of the table. The query planner checks the indexes to see which way it thinks will work better.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know of any restriction, I prefer not mixing join and filter operations. I prefer the `JOIN` approach, but that's only me:

```
select *
from notes
left join users on notes.user_id = users.user_id
where notes.game_id = 1
```

As Barmar said in his comment, use `EXPLAIN` to check the execution plan for each query. If there's no difference, then use the one that's clearer to you (and easier to reproduce/mantain).

Comment: I'm not asking for the sake of readability/clarity/maintainability- I specifically want to know for performance reasons (all are more or less equally clear anyways). Depending on the answer, it might warrant much of the mysql throughout our app to be re-written (so it isn't a case of a one-off test). Given how simple the use case is, I'm surprised I'm not flooded with strong and clear "the right way to do it" answers.

Comment: @Phildo Test them yourself with `explain`... that will be faster than asking (and hoping to get an answer you're willing to accept)

Comment: @Phildo And... given you've posted the `explain` results: you can discard right away the subquery option... subqueries are (frequently) more expensive than other options... there are cases for which you need them, but for this kind of thing, I would'nt use them

Comment: The `EXPLAIN` isn't sufficient for me (either they lack the information I need, or I am too inexperienced to see the info within them). Mainly, what is the order of operations? because if filter is first at the cost of botched indices, it is worth it to do it that way even w/ subquery overhead with a sufficiently small result because it'll only have to join order of magnitudes less than otherwise. looking to understand what is going on for the sake of applying knowledge to codebase.

Comment: I'm not trying to sound entitled to an answer from the community- I assumed this must be a well-known question (the question is rather simple...). If not, and it's actually worth me creating a rigorous test suite to benchmark the various methods and release it open source, I might do that. But I don't want to waste my time if this is common knowledge.